# Can multiple users be logged in to the same email account in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, email, exception

I am developing an application where in the case of an exception an email is sent to my email account automatically - the point is that I will be using my email account and each user will automatically login using my credentials - so will this cause a problem asuming I dispose the object after each sending?

Comment: C# doesn't have email accounts. This question doesn't have enough detail to be answerable.

Comment: well...i will most likely chose your answer later for creativity...

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question, I was trying to get you to clarify. Your comment to TheVillageIdiot's answer says that you're using Gmail and the `SmtpClient` class—those are details that should have been in your question in the first place. If you want quality help, you have to spend some time writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

I regullarly use this mechanism to get error details (in small apps, when not using Elmah or log4net :D ). Don't know which service you are using to send emails. I use Gmail (smtp.gmail.com, port 587) and my email id and password is used only to authenticate to use smtp server not log into my email account. So you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Namely, I am using gmail and using the "SmtpClient" in c#, as long as the "Mail" type. Then simply send the message the dispose it. It doesn't make sense for multiple logging to be impossible this way, as there is no sessions etc. Needless to say i have created a special new email for this very purpose and have obfuscated the code for best anti reverse hackable measures.